# TouchImageView doesn't show animated gif

Tags: android, android-glide, touchimageview

I am using Glide to load animated gif images to ImageView:

```
Glide.with(this).load(gifUrl).into(imageView)
```

This works fine except when I use [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) , the TouchImageView shows only a static image, no animation.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Glide.with(this).asGif().load(gifUrl).into(new SimpleTarget<GifDrawable>() {
 @Override
       public void onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Transition<? super GifDrawable> transition) {
              resource.start();
              view.setImageDrawable(resource);
              view.setZoom(1f);
       }
});
```

Comment: This works with static GIF images, but not for GIF animation. Animation will be displayed as static image.